# Derivative with respect to reciprocal $\frac{d}{dx^{-1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there some easy way to calculate the derivative of a reciprocal of a variable, $\frac{d}{dx^{-1}}$, in terms of the familiar derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the chain rule$$\frac{d}{dx^{-1}}f(x)=\frac{df/dx}{dx^{-1}/dx}=\frac{df/dx}{-x^{-2}}=-x^2\frac{df}{dx},$$i.e. $\frac{d}{dx^{-1}}=-x^2\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.